# LINQ InheritanceMappingAttribute Code property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the purpose of the `Code` property of `InheritanceMappingAttribute` atribute?
The documentation says that it's related to the `IsDiscriminator` property. However, I do not know the `IsDiscriminator` property too.

I'm Reading this exemple:

```
public enum ShapeType
{
    Square = 0, Circle = 1
}
[Table(Name = "Shape")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = ShapeType.Square, Type = typeof(Square),
    IsDefault = true)]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = ShapeType.Circle, Type = typeof(Circle))]

abstract public class Shape
{
    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
    public ShapeType ShapeType = 0;
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    [Column]
    public int Side = 0;
}
public class Circle : Shape
{
    [Column]
    public int Radius = 0;
}
```

On my case, I have three tables, `Persons`, `Clients`, `Functionaries`. And three class `Person`(abstract), `Client` and `Functionary`. That is, in `Person` table are the common data between `Client` and `Functionary`. In the `Clients` table are the data of `Client`. And in the `Functionaries` table are the data of `Functionary`.

How do the mapping in this case?

Answer (score 0):

With EF6 you don't have to configure the mappings. Just create the classes and EF do the rest.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Clients")]
public class Client : Person
{
}

[Table("Functionaries")]
public class Functionary : Person
{
}
```

EF creates 3 tables and set the relations.

[image: table mapping]

Add types

```
context.Persons.Add(new Client());
context.Persons.Add(new Functionary());
```

You can query the types with

```
Persons.OfType<Client>()
```